# Remove trailing newline from esyscmd in m4

Tags: bash, shell, m4

I'm using m4 to create some basic macros and I realize that when using `esyscmd` there's a trailing new line added to a string when the command is run.

Example:

```
define(MY_HOSTNAME, esyscmd(`hostname'))
MY_HOSTNAME
Some other text...
```

Renders:

```
> my.host.name
>
> Some other text...
```

(complete with a trailing new line)

By adding `dnl` at the end of the define (or esyscmd) nothing appears to happen and there's still a trailing newline.

What's the best way to drop the trailing newline when calling `esyscmd` in m4?

Comment: Hm, from the shell I'd `echo -n \`hostname\``...

Comment: @Wrikken i would submit your comment as an answer. its perfectly valid and a good alternative to devnulls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*nix systems have `tr` by default.  Make use of that:

```
define(MY_HOSTNAME, esyscmd(sh -c "hostname | tr -d '\n'"))
```

and you'd get rid of the trailing newline!

Answer (score 5):

devnull's example is good but, M4 has a builtin `tr` as well. Here's what I'm doing:

```
define(CMD_OUTPUT, esyscmd(`sass --style=compressed foo.sass'))
define(NL,`
')
translit(CMD_OUTPUT, NL)
```

Someone a little better with M4 could tighten that into a single macro.

Comment: I can't nest backticks, but here's a tighter version that includes the translit call in the body of CMD_OUTPUT:
`define([chomp], [translit([$1],NL,[])])` and
`define([CMD_OUTPUT], [chomp(esyscmd([$1]))])`      
**NOTE** if you directly quote the `esyscmd` call like so `chomp([esyscmd(...)])` the chomp won't work, at least not under m4 v1.4.18

Answer (score 2):

An alternative would be

```
echo -n `hostname`
```

No pipe, but backticks, whatevers suits your fancy.

Comment: The newer syntax (e.g. `$(...)`) would be better, if only because the user wouldn't need to configure `m4` to use something other than the backtick as the open-quote symbol.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`translit`](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/manual/m4.html#Translit) macro. If no third argument is passed, the list of characters passed in the second argument are deleted from the first argument. So in your case, your first argument to `translit` would be `` esyscmd(`hostname') ``, the second argument would be the newline character, and you would not pass a third argument. **Note:** the literal newline character below causes the macro definition to be on two lines:

```
define(`MY_HOSTNAME', translit(esyscmd(`hostname'), `
'))dnl

foo MY_HOSTNAME bar  # -> foo Dans-Macbook-Pro.local bar
```